# Defining a table: Allow nulls or stick with "n/a"

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a simple design question for defining a table. I have to read in strings which are numeric values but also can be "n/a". Now I have two options. I could define a column as varchar and allow "n/a" or I define such column as numeric ( float ) and allow nulls.

Since I would like to do aggregation I tend to store the values as floats instead of casting them all the time. What's your opinion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite doesn't really have data types. It has "storage classes" instead. Here's what that means for you.

```
sqlite> create table test (r real);
sqlite> insert into test values (123.456);
sqlite> insert into test values (654.321);
sqlite> insert into test values ('n/a');
```

SQLite accepts 'n/a' without an error or a warning.

```
sqlite> select * from test;
r
----------
123.456
654.321
n/a
```

It *stored* the string literal 'n/a' in a column declared as real.

```
sqlite> select sum(r) from test;
sum(r)
----------
777.777
```

Aggregates work without any special effort.

Whether this is a Good Thing or a Bad Thing is debatable. But it *is* how SQLite is designed to work.

Answer (score 4):

A numeric column and `"n/a"` → `null` translation looks best to me.

- Numeric values can be reasonably compared as numbers (which is greater, `'3'` or `'25'`, as opposed to `3` and `25`).
- Numeric values can be reasonably summed, averaged, etc.
- Is random junk (not a number, not an `'n/a'`) creeps into your data, you see it immediately.
- The table is smaller, and an index by a numeric column is smaller; can be important if data are many and RAM is scarce.

Comment: Very good rationale on why storing as numbers (and thus allowing nulls in values) makes sense.